# request taking approx 20 - 30 sec in node.js server

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I wrote server on node.js using connect module.When i make single request it is working fine.But when i make 2/3 simultaneous requests to server then chrome browser starts load my localhost and its status shows pending for 20-30 seconds.

On close observation, i observed that http request is not reaching the server for this much amount of time.So what can be possible issue with my code??

PS:I got my questions related to this here on stackoverflow but from none of them i got the required answer.
Code is here :

```js
var connect = require('connect');

function data(){
 this.name='aman';
 this.age='25';
}

var my_data,count=0;

var app = connect()

 .use(connect.bodyParser())

 .use(connect.static('public')) 
 .use(function (req, res) {
  if(req.url === '/favicon.ico'){
   console.log('favicon req. prevented');
  }
  else{
   if(req.url === "/revert"){
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   my_data=new data();
   my_data.name=req.body.name;
   my_data.age=req.body.age;
   console.log('top' + count);
   count++;
   res.write(JSON.stringify(my_data));
   res.end();
   }
   else{
    console.log('bottom' + count);
    count++;
    res.write(JSON.stringify(my_data));
    res.end();
   }
  }

 })
 .listen(3000);

console.log('server started');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling `res.end();` in your `if(req.url === '/favicon.ico')` block so the browser is probably exhausting its pool of connections trying to download favicons.